# How to solve Itext issue while adding jasper:1.11.0 plugin for grails 2.4.4 version

Tags: grails, jasper-reports, grails-plugin, ggts, grails-2.4

I am trying to migrate a grails project from grails version 1.3.7 to 2.4.4.In that I need to add Jasper Plugin jasper:1.11.0.I already used Jasper:1.5.3 plugin for version 1.3.7,its working fine.

The problem is while adding jasper:1.11.0 plugin for version 2.4.4 in BuildConfig.groovy under configuration folder then I gave grails-> refresh dependencies command.
Its start downloading the required plugin and try to install it .During installation it showing  the below error

**

### Error | Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js2 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

**

[Console showing error while adding plugins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MvEz.png)

[Console showing error while adding plugins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm1tz.jpg)

The same issue i am facing while doing in via Command Prompt.
My Configuration are

GGTS : 3.6.4.RELEASE

Groovy-Comipler : 2.3.10

Grails : 2.4.4

Jdk : 1.7.0_75

Repositories i am using buildconfig.groovy file is

```
repositories 
{       
 inherits true    
        grailsPlugins()    
        grailsHome()    
        mavenLocal()    
        grailsCentral()    
        mavenCentral()

       mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core"    
        mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins"           
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding additional mavenRepo.

I am having internet restriction issues so I can't find the necessary repo you should add.

Try these:

```
mavenRepo  "http://repo.spring.io/release" 
mavenRepo  "http://jaspersoft.artifactoryonline.com/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/" 
mavenRepo  "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/maven2/"
```